# Unable to completely populate HTML table from XML data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, rest

Here I am trying to populate an HTML table with the XML data returned by an AJAX call.

My issue here is I am unable to populate HTML table completely. Since, I am very new to AJAX I am unable to figure out how the XML interpretation works and how to decode the root cause of the error.

Here is my webpage code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        table, th, td 
        {
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td 
        {
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Enter Book Details</h1><br>

    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/mysql/glarimy/lib/addbook" onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">
        Title :<br> <input type = "text" name = "title" ><br>
        Author :<br><input type = "text" name = "author" ><br>
        Price : <br><input type = "text" name = "price" ><br>
        No. of Pages :<br><input type="text" name = "pages" ><br>
        <input type = "submit" id="submit" value = "Add Book">
        <input type = "reset" value ="Reset"><br><br>
    </form>

    <button onclick = "location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/mysql/glarimy/lib/getall'" type = "button">Get all book data in XML</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get all books data </button>
    <table id="demo"></table>   
    <script>
        function loadXMLDoc() 
        {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
            {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
                {
                  myFunction(this);
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/mysql/glarimy/lib/getall", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
        function myFunction(xml) 
        {
            var i;
            var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
            var table="<tr><th>ISBN</th><th>Title</th><th>Author</th><th>Price</th><th>No. of Pages</th></tr>";
            var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book");
            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
            { 
                table += "<tr><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("isbn")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>";
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td></td>";
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("pages")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><tr>";
           }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
        }
    </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

I get the XML data as below from the AJAX call

```
<books>
     <book>     
          <author>mark</author>
          <isbn>1</isbn>
          <pages>500</pages>
          <price>2000.0</price>
          <title>java</title>
     </book>
     <book>
          <author>john</author>
          <isbn>2</isbn>
          <pages>100</pages>
          <price>1000.0</price>
          <title>advancedjava</title>
     </book>
     <book>
          <author>paul</author>
          <isbn>3</isbn>
          <pages>500</pages>
          <price>500.0</price>
          <title>tomcat</title>
     </book>
     <book>
          <author>jack</author>
          <isbn>4</isbn>
          <pages>1000</pages>
          <price>5000.0</price>
          <title>rest</title>
     </book>
</books>
```

The output I am getting is 
[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0oiy.png)

Can anyone explain me how that AJAX code is actually working? I am unable to trace out that XML decoding part.

Updated Output : [image: Click this]

Comment: the order of your for loop in which you're adding the rows to the table is incorrect according to the `var table` so that is the problem of the wrong order of items in the table

Comment: @KevinKloet Can u please elaborate your comment? I have made some changes to my questions, check once.

Comment: even after your edit in your for loop the last 2 `td`'s added to the table are reversed, `ISBN, Title, Author, Price, No. of Pages` is the order in `var table` and `ISBN, Title, Author, No. of Pages, Price` is the order in the for loop.

Comment: @KevinKloet Please check the new image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the building of your table. You are closing a `<tr>` tag when you don't need to and have too many semicolons. This is the fix:

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
{ 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("isbn")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>"+
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("pages")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>"+
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
}
```

You can see in this image the problems with your code:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code? Note that you have a semicolons (`;`) that you should remove there...

Comment: That's a silly mistake I have done. But even after I change it I am not getting the 5 column data, only two columns are getting displayed. Check the edits I have made in my question.

Comment: You still have semicolons in your question (after edit). double check.

Comment: This is the reference I used for my code (http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlfile.asp) Which semicolon you are referring to?

Comment: lets start with copy & paste of the entire `for ( ...) { ... }` loop from my answer to your code.

Comment: Added image to the answer, check it

Comment: @Sarath Raja `;` should be `+` in those rules

Comment: @SarathRaja, did you check?

Comment: @KevinKloet Thank you. Now, I am getting 4 column data but the final one is still displaying in a single row.

Comment: @Dekel Yes, I have checked and thanks for your time. :)

Comment: If the answer is correct - please mark it as correct (you have the V on the left).

Comment: @Dekel Sure thing.

Comment: @SarathRaja if you followed this answer you should get 5 columns of data

Comment: @KevinKloet `for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
   { 
       table += "<tr><td>" +
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("isbn")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td><td>" +
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td><td>"+
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td></td>"+
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td><td>" +
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("pages")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td><tr>" ;
   }`

Comment: You still have wrong open/close of the td tags there... write them more carefully

Comment: @Dekel `for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
   { 
       table += "<tr><td>" +
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("isbn")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td><td>" +
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td><td>"+
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td><td>"+
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td><td>" +
       x[i].getElementsByTagName("pages")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
       "</td></tr>" ;
   }` Still I get the same output as the new image

Comment: Even after the HTML tag edits, I am not getting the 5 column data. But getting only 4 column data as shown in the image above. @Dekel

Comment: I'm 99.9% sure something is wrong there (you didn't save/refresh/upload the correct file to the server) because the code looks correct.

Comment: @Dekel I am sorry I got the output correctly. I am using Maven and it did not updated automatically even after I rebuilt it. Once I closed the eclipse and restarted it I got the output correctly. Thanks a bunch to you. Your help is Appreciated.